# Can you use DATEDIF fx in google sheets without first entering the dates into cells?

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, datediff

I'm taking a class in Data Analytics, and I'm trying to improve my Google Sheets and Excel skills. (I'm a beginner!)

I'm trying to gain fluency with using DATEDIF. When I type =DATEDIF(MM/DD/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY, "D") it returns an error. If I put the dates into two cells first, and then type =DATEDIF (cell, cell, "D") it works just fine.

Is that just how DATEDIF is supposed to work or am I doing something wrong? I'm making sure my dates are formatted correctly, and consistently. Thank you!

I tried entering the dates in the formula, rather than in cells first.

Comment: put the dates in quotes: `=DATEDIF("MM/DD/YYYY", "MM/DD/YYYY", "D")`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239):

> `TO_DATE(10/10/2000)` is interpreted as `TO_DATE(0.0005)`, the quotient of 10 divided by 10 divided by 2000.

Use this syntax:

```
=datedif(datevalue("2023-01-01"), datevalue("2023-12-31"), "d")
```

...or simply let Sheets autoconvert text strings to dates, as suggested in the comment, like this:

```
=datedif("2023-01-01", "2023-12-31", "d")
```

...or skip `datedif()` altogether, like this:

```
="2023-12-31" - "2023-01-01"
```

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).